# Find the limit of a sequence $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-3}})$

Tags: limits

I am trying to solve this : $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-3}})$ but I always end up with $\infty$ times $0$ which is undefined

I tried for eg $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-3}}) (\frac {\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-3}}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-3}})$$
which resulted in:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {n^{3/2}(\sqrt{1+\frac3n}+\sqrt{1-\frac3n}-\sqrt{1+\frac3n-\frac1{n^2}-\frac3{n^3}}-\sqrt{1-\frac3n-\frac1{n^2}+\frac3{n^3}})}{6}$$

but I cannot seem to find any other solutions

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-3}}&=\left(\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-3}}\right)\left(\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-3}}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-3}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-3}}{6(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})}\\\\
&\frac{1}{6\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+3/n}+\sqrt{1-3/n}}{1+\sqrt{1-1/n^2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 2):

$$n-\sqrt{n^2-1}=\frac{n^2-(n^2-1)}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}\sim\frac1{2n}$$
as $n\to\infty$.
$$\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-3}=\frac{n+3-(n-3)}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-3}}\sim\frac3{\sqrt n}$$
as $n\to\infty$.

What do you get when you divide one by the other?

Answer (score 1):

Set $1/x=h^2$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-h^4}}{h\sqrt{1+3h^2}-\sqrt{1-3h^2}}=\lim \dfrac{1-(1-h^4)}{h(1+3h^2-(1-3h^2))}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{1+3h^2}+\sqrt{1-3h^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-h^4}}=?$$